# Weird If/Else Problem with Javascript & Express

Tags: javascript, express, pg-promise

I'm having a problem checking if a object is undefined or not. Weirdly, this error doesn't occur in Mac OSX but on Windows I get a "cannot read property of to_char" error. Hoping you folks can help me!

Here is the code:

```
let accountInfo = {};
let recentForms = {}

  db.tx(async (t) => {
    accountInfo = await t.one(
      "SELECT * from useraccount INNER JOIN company on useraccount.company_id = company.id WHERE username = $1",
      [req.params.username]
    );
    recentForms = await t.any(
      "SELECT f.form_id, TO_CHAR(f.date_submitted :: DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd'), f2.form_name from formresponse f INNER JOIN forms f2 on f.form_id = f2.form_id WHERE f.company_id = $1",
      [accountInfo.company_id]
    );
    return accountInfo, recentForms;
  })
    .then((data) => {
      // We need to compare the form submitted date to our date today to determine if completed.
      // First we need to see if to_char exists and then decalre the forms date as a date variable
      if (recentForms[0].to_char !== undefined){
        formDate = new Date(recentForms[0].to_char);
      }
      else{
        formDate = '2120-01-12' 
      }
```

Basically, if pg-promise returns something for recentForms[0].to_char, i want to turn it into a javascript date variable. If there's nothing, I want to set formDate as a far in the future variable. I can't get the program to execute that if statement though, atleast on Windows.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't know about the platform-specific issue (mismatched node versions? different postgres versions?), but I do see one bug: JS doesn't have multiple return. Instead of `return accountInfo, recentForms` (which is actually returning recentForms and using the comma operator to basically discard accountInfo`, you could `return { accountInfo, recentForms }` and then pull them out in `.then(({ accountInfo, recentForms })`. That would also let you get rid of the reassignment and unscoped variables.

Comment: So I actually am missing about 80 lines of code beyond these ones, that use accountInfo & Recent Forms as inputs for other sql queries, but I didn't know the other facts thanks for that.

Comment: I think I solved this by changing if(recentForms[0].to_char !== undefined) to 

if(recentForms.length > 0) 

I don't know if I'll ever run into any errors though

Comment: Well, what you changed it to is just if there are any items, what you changed it from was checking a specific property on the first item. Both checks (length, then the undefined check) would help prevent any errors, but that still doesn't explain why the result would differ across platforms.

Comment: Yeah, I mean I would like to check for that specific item but I guess its just one of those weird errors. It shouldn't be a different postgres version due to me using RDS but I'm very very very new and just learning as I go.

Thanks for your help again!